# Load values from txt to variables in namespace

Tags: c++, namespace

I am currently working in an aleady developed C++ project. The existing files are the following:

```
-main.cpp
-HydroModel.cpp
-ODESys.cpp

-HydroModel.hpp
-ODESys.hpp
-ODESysSol.hpp
```

In the file HydroModel.hpp there are some constants defined in the namespace config, for example

```
 namespace config 
 { 
     const unsigned int dim = 40; 
     const unsigned int NaN = 10101; ... 
 }
```

This file is being included in main.cpp, ODESysSol.hpp and HydroModel.cpp. These constants are being used over and over in those files.

However, these constants are not always the same, as they change depending on the case study analyzed. The idea is to take out these variables into a txt file in order to avoid compiling each time that the case study changes.

I know it would be easy if the variables are being defined inside a function or the main(), but so far I didn't find a way to do it in the preprocessor.

Is it possible to load the txt file and define the variables inside the namespace or I have to rewrite everything that is related to those variables?

Comment: They're variables. Why can't you just set their values from a config file at run time?

Comment: Show us please one example to make clear which syntax was used to define the constants (or variables?). Are they are just preprocessor symbols? Static "const" variables? Or what else?

Comment: @Useless, can you please provide me with a little more information about that? I think that could be what I am looking for.

Comment: @DocBrown, here is the example
namespace config {
    const unsigned int dim = 40;
    const unsigned int NaN = 10101;
...
}

Comment: @AndresG: thanks for the clarification. By the way, did you see the "edit" button below your question? Guess what it is for. Comments are not well suited for adding formatted code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your header file HydroModel.hpp to

```
namespace config 
{ 
    extern unsigned int dim; 
    extern unsigned int NaN;
}
```

In HydroModel.cpp write

```
namespace config 
{ 
    unsigned int dim; 
    unsigned int NaN;
}
```

That way, you won't have to rewrite much of your existing code.

Now all what remains to you is to implement a function which initializes those variables from the text file. Afterwards make sure this function is called when the program starts, before any other code tries to access the variables.

Comment: And make sure that nobody *modifies* them.

Comment: @NicolBolas: first, one needs to make it work, then make it nice ;-)

Comment: For more on extern see [when-to-use-extern-in-c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10422034/when-to-use-extern-in-c)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I think this is the type of solution that I am looking for. I did the changes but I didn't implement the function to load the values from a file, I just assigned the values as soon as the main() begins (just for testing). However now the program became terribly slow.. any suggestions? Thanks again!

Comment: @AndresG: I suggest you measure which part exactly is slow and isolate the problem. If you can reduce it to a minimal working, reproducible code snippet, and you are still unsure why it is slow, you can ask a related question on Stackoverflow.

Comment: found the problem... it was my mistake, now it is working perfectly, thank you very much!! you saved me a lot of time :D

Answer (score 4):

If you want to "avoid compiling", then it has to be data loaded *at runtime*. It can't be something from a global compile-time `const` variable. You can have an object with (perhaps `static`) functions that return these values as loaded from a file. I suggest functions rather than exposing variables directly to prevent the outside world from modifying their values.

But they can't just be global `const` variables.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid recompiling, then some config file that would be loaded at runtime needs to be used.

You can also use ifdef and then use preprocessor directives in project files to choose the value of a constant, but that requires recompiling.